# How to make active admin use the users table already used by devise and cancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have been using devise for authentication and cancan for authorization in my application. The application worked fine with them. But now i wanted to use active admin to manage all the users that are already in my application that are being used by devise and cancan. Active admin creates its own admin_users table for the users. how can i make active_admin use the users and roles table that was previously in use? thanx for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you already have the `users` table created, so you should skip the creation of this table.

Running:

```
rails generate active_admin:install --skip-users
```

And don't forget to run:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Be attempt to change the authentication method on the `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` file. Also make sure you have the `current_admin_user` method created, if you don't, you can just modify it to the devise defaults (`current_user` method).

You will have to modify the http method used in the logout link to `:delete`.

```
config.logout_link_method = :delete
```

And the route path to the logout action.

```
config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
```

For better understand the authenticate method, I'm pasting my `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` relevant code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  #
  # redirect registered users to a profile page
  # of to the admin dashboard if the user is an administrator
  #
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    resource.role == 'admin' ? admin_dashboard_path : user_path(resource)
  end

  def authenticate_admin_user!
    raise SecurityError unless current_user.try(:role) == 'admin'
  end

  rescue_from SecurityError do |exception|
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Hope it helps you and maybe someone else.

Answer (score 5):

By default it will create a new Devise user / model called AdminUser. To change the name of the user class, simply pass the class as the last argument:

```
rails generate active_admin:install User
```

http://activeadmin.info/docs/0-installation.html

http://activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#authentication

Answer (score 0):

if you already ran the activeadmin commands.... you can use existing users table by changing 
admin_user to user in active_admin.rb in initializer and define an ability for admin in cancan ability model.Also you have to do something like authorize admin to authorize DSL